# смена значения CheckBox другой формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма, на ней есть кнопка, которая вызывает еще одну форму (подключенная dll'ка) с настройками и `CheckBox'ом`. Нужно чтобы по нажатию на `CheckBox` отменялся вызов метода.

первая форма с кнопкой, которая вызывает вспомогательную форму с настройками

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateSetupForm setupForm = new UpdateSetupForm();
            if (!setupForm.disableUpdateChb.Checked)
            {
                Update();
            }                
        }

private void updateSetupBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateSetupForm setupForm = new UpdateSetupForm();
            setupForm.ShowDialog();
        }
```

`UpdateSetupForm` это подключенная dll'ка, в ней содержится `CheckBox`

Подскажите, почему у меня не меняется состояние `CheckBox'a`. У меня при любом состоянии вызывается метод

Comment: Вы постоянно создаете НОВЫЙ объект вашей формы, который имеет значения по умолчанию и который не как не изменяется вашем кодом после. Вынесите `UpdateSetupForm setupForm` за пределы методов и дальше только 1 раз инициализируйте и уже работайте с этим объектом.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не помогло

Comment: а где код, который меняет состояние чекбокса ?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц ну я так понимаю он не обязателен в моем случае, если Вы имеете ввиду `CheckedChanged`, это если менять состояние с помощью переменной true/false

Comment: тогда еще раз, по порядку расскажите: У вас есть 2 формы (2 класса, как я понимаю). По нажатию на кнопку в одной (пусть будет `форма(класс)-родитель)` открывается вторая `форма(класс)-ребенок`. А теперь главный вопрос: на какой из форм находится `checkBox`, и в каком из классов работает метод, который нужно отменить. И если он уже работает, то когда он начинает работать.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц `checkBox` находится на форме, которая вызывается по нажатию на кнопку, доступ к ней с формы-родителя происходит по ссылке, которую подключаю, а метод, который нужно отменить находится на форме-родителе

Comment: тогда, думаю, нужно с помощью делегата подписаться на форме-родителе на изменение состояния `checkbox`а формы-ребенка. Если никто не ответит, то позже напишу ответ